# How can i Get All days of Next and Previous dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date, datetime

I want to get all days of next and Prev dates.
I have Three buttons there are PrevDate, TodayDate, NextDate.
When i am clicking 1st time on prevDate button it should show previous date and clicking 2nd time it show day before day similarly it should show all prev dates when i am clicking.. samething in Nextdate also it show next day of date. 2nd time clicking it show day after day of date..
This is my HTML Code:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div class="col-sm-10" >   
   <button style="font-size:14px" ng-click="prevBtn()">Previous day</button>
   <button style="font-size:14px" ng-click="todayBtn()" >&nbsp;Today&nbsp;</button>
   <button style="font-size:14px" ng-click="nextBtn()" >Next day</button>
   {{date}}
 </div>
</body>
```

app.js Code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   var today = new Date();

       $scope.prevBtn = function(){
           var yesterday = new Date(today);
           yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
           var dd = yesterday.getDate();
           var mm = yesterday.getMonth()+1; 
           var yyyy = yesterday.getFullYear();
           yesterday = dd+'-'+mm+'-'+yyyy;  
           console.log(yesterday);
           $scope.date = yesterday;
       }
});
```

This code showing prev date only..
I want to get all days of Prev dates....
Please Help me... Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep a reference for current date

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var today = new Date();

  var curDay = new Date(today);
  $scope.prevBtn = function() {

    curDay.setDate(curDay.getDate() - 1);
    var dd = curDay.getDate();
    var mm = curDay.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = curDay.getFullYear();
    var yesterday = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
    console.log(yesterday);
    $scope.date = yesterday;
  }
});
```

the following snippet may help you for your sample app

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var today = new Date();

  var curDay = new Date(today);
  $scope.prevBtn = function() {

    curDay.setDate(curDay.getDate() - 1);
    showDate();

  }

  $scope.todayBtn = function() {
    curDay = new Date(today);
    showDate();
  };

  $scope.nextBtn = function() {
    curDay.setDate(curDay.getDate() + 1);
    showDate();
  };

  function showDate() {
    var dd = curDay.getDate();
    var mm = curDay.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = curDay.getFullYear();
    var dateStr = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
    console.log(dateStr);
    $scope.date = dateStr;
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <button style="font-size:14px" ng-click="prevBtn()">Previous day</button>
    <button style="font-size:14px" ng-click="todayBtn()">&nbsp;Today&nbsp;</button>
    <button style="font-size:14px" ng-click="nextBtn()">Next day</button> {{date}}
  </div>
</body>
```